# how can I make a custom progress bar widget like that?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build a progress bar as it shown on image.How can I do it? [image]

I tried percent_indicator packet,but there is not a progress bar like that in this packet.How can I  do it?
It seems I have to write it manually...However I do not have any idea how to do it.Is there a specific packet for this purpose?

Comment: Refer [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator)

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Thanks but I want to get the same view of progress bar.In percent_indicator there are only linear and circular percent_bar

Comment: So you need the progress bar with animation based on percentage right?

Comment: @AkshayGupta yes sir

Comment: How do get the number for progress bar ?